# Hypothesis Testing with Two-Variable Hypotheses, Arbitrary Significance (Neyman-Pearson Lemma)

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm trying to catch up in my statistics class before finals and I am posed with this "try at home" question in our notes. It asks me to find the best critical region for testing a null hypothesis vs. an alternative hypothesis at an unspecified/arbitrary significance $\alpha$ using the Neyman-Pearson lemma.

---

The question starts familiarly: "Let $X_1,...,X_n$ denote a random iid sample of size n from $N(μ,σ^2)$ for $μ ∈ \mathbb{R},σ^2 > 0$. Find the best *yadda yadda yadda*" -- but I am thrown off by the given hypotheses:

$H_0:μ = 0,σ^2 = 2$

$H_1:μ = 1,σ^2 = 4$

Maybe my understanding is further behind than I thought, but I am unsure of what to do with both $\mu \text{ and } \sigma^2$ denoted in the hypotheses.

I attempted a solution starting by finding the likelihood function $L$ for the normal distribution. Then I constructed $L_0 \text{ and }L_1$ by plugging in the values set by $H_0 \text{ and } H_1$, respectively, and set up $\frac{L_1}{L_0} > k$, but (if that's even the right thing to do here) I'm freezing up from there.

Do I just keep plugging away at the algebra until I get to something like $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i > \text{"some function"}$ and denote the critical set that way? If not, I'm hoping a little hint can guide me in the right direction...

Related -- are there additional considerations to make when determining the power of this test?

Comment: If you are looking for a most powerful test, then you are right to set up $L_1/L_0>k$ by Neyman-Pearson lemma. And since such a test is always based on a sufficient statistic, your critical region would depend on that.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. In solving this, my problem is really coming with $\theta_2$ being different for $H_0$ and $H_1$. Because of that none of the terms in $\frac{L_1}{L_0}$ seem to cancel out nicely. I'm trying to get $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i$ on one side of the inequality, but I still have a $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i^2$ term that I don't know what to do with. I'm wondering if I made a misstep that is causing some ugliness -- as a problem from our notes, I expected the math to work out nicely

Comment: If I can divide $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i$ by $n$ to get the mean of $x$, can I move that term in the inequality and make $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i^2$ my test statistic?

Comment: In theory, your test statistic should be a function of $(\sum x_i,\sum x_i^2)$ because both $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are unknown.

Comment: Ohhhhh, that does make sense. Thank you! So I group those terms and denote them as my test statistic $T(x)$ and then go ahead set up probabilities of false alarm and detection from there like usual?